# Strcmp — loop while no input

Tags: c, loops, strcmp, c-strings

This program does the following:

1. Scans a string of text **char input[15];**
2. Compares it to **char password[ ] = "1sure";**
3. Loops if the strings do not match.
4. Terminates if the strings match.

The program loops while the strings do not match. However, I also want the program **to loop if nothing is input** and the user simply presses enter. I tried using an `isgraph` function but this causes the program to crash. I commented that section out in the code. Can someone suggest how to get the program to loop if there is no input?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char password[] = "1sure";
    char input[15];

    do
    {
        printf("Password: ");
        scanf("%s", input);

        if(strcmp(password,input)==0)
        {
            printf("Password accepted.");
            putchar('\n');
            return(0);
        }
        /*else if(isgraph(input)==0)
        {
            printf("No input detected."); //Program crashes with this segment.
            continue;
        }*/
        else
        {
            printf("\nInvalid password.\n");
            continue;
        }
    }
    while(1);
}
```

Comment: Use [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead of `scanf` and cull the newline.

Comment: The call to `scanf`, `scanf("%s", input);` will not complete until the user enters some non white space text. Just pressing Enter will not result in nothing being read to `input` -- the program will just wait.

Comment: It is simpler include the newline in the output message when the password is accepted than to use `printf()` plus `putchar()`.  Don't forget that standard error is intended for reporting error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program could look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main( void )
{
    char password[] = "1sure";
    char input[15];

    do
    {
        printf("\nPassword: ");

        if ( fgets( input, sizeof( input ), stdin ) == NULL )
        {
            printf( "An error occured or input was interrupted\n" );
            return 0;
        }

        size_t n = strlen( input );

        while ( n && isspace( input[n-1] ) ) input[--n] = '\0';

        if ( input[0] == '\0' )
        {
            printf("No input detected.\n");
            continue;
        }
        else if( strcmp( password, input ) == 0 )
        {
            printf("Password accepted.\n");
            return(0);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nInvalid password.\n");
            continue;
        }
    } while(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `scanf` function skips leading whitespace when used with `%s` and most other specifiers. Whitespace includes newlines, so it is not possible to detect a blank line with `scanf`.

Instead you can read a line with fgets. Note that I have added error checking:

```
if ( ! fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin) )
    break;
```

Unfortunately `fgets` has a quirk in that it puts the newline character into the buffer, so you have to remove that; one way to do that is:

```
char *newline = strchr(input, '\n');
if ( newline )
    *newline = '\0';
```

Then you can go on to `strcmp` and the rest of your loop.

---

Other notes:  If you didn't get compiler errors for `isgraph(input)` then you need to figure out how to invoke your compiler properly. That code is illegal and if errors are not shown then you may be missing out on other useful information that the compiler could be telling you.

Also, there is no point having `else` after `return`. A return statement cannot fail. A `continue` as the last line of the loop is similarly redundant.

Comment: `if ( input[strlen(input) - 1] == '\n' )` can invoke UB.  Recommend http://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/2410359 or insure `*input != 0`.

Comment: @chux I don't see how it can cause UB; `fgets` cannot return non-null and also yield anything other than a non-empty null-terminated string. (Well, I guess it could if the buffer size was 1)

Comment: `fgets()` reads a _line_ (`char` up to and including `'\n'`), not a _string_ (`char` up to and including `'\0'`).  Input could contain embedded `'\0'` such as "\0abc\n".  `fgets()` in this case fills `input` with  "\0abc\n\0".  Then `input[strlen(input) - 1] = '\0';` is setting a value before the array `input`.

Comment: @chux well, text streams are not allowed to contain `\0`, and `stdin` is a text stream. But I will concede that there could be buggy implementations around so my code is unsafe in practice. Fixing!

Comment: Hmm  "text streams are not allowed to contain `\0`"  I see nothing in C the asserts that - as troublesome as embedded null  characters are.  Also consider text file encoded UTF16 which has plenty of embedded `'\0'` and code unsuspectingly attempting  to `fgets()` that.

Comment: @chux I see nothing in the standard either... I must have trusted some untrustworthy text :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the return value of scanf (it should return 1) to continue the rest of the code

```c
printf("Password: ");
char line[15];
if(fgets(line,15,stdin)!=NULL) {
   if(scanf("%s", input)==1) {
      if(strcmp(password,input)==0) {
   ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Just checking the return value of `scanf("%s",input)` is not a complete fix for all the reasons enumerated above (leading newlines, undefined behaviour...)

Comment: @chqrlie thanks for the feedback I will amend the answer

Answer (score 0):

Simply check the return value of `scanf`.

```
if ( scanf("%s",input) != 1 )
       continue;
...
...
```

Or else you can do like this.

```
while( scanf("%s",input) != 1 )// It will continue the loop until the correct input come.
       continue;
```

Comment: This won't work unforturnately. The `scanf("%s")` can only fail if EOF occurs.  `%s` consumes leading whitespace, including newlines.

Comment: `scanf("%s",input)` can cause a buffer overflow.  Carefully crafted input may cause an invalid password to be accepted (among other undefined behaviour)